# Magento 2 afterGetSpecialPrice plugin won't change special price in WEBAPI

Tags: plugins, module, magento2

I've implemented a custom magento 2 plugin to change special price for some products programmatically. It was a success for the frontend , but still in webapi I'm getting original special price.

**di.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\PromotionManagementInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\PromotionManagement"/>

            <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
            <plugin name="change_product" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
        </type>

</config>
```

**Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product.php**

> afterGetSpecialPrice() not called when using webapi

```
.....
  public function afterGetSpecialPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
            if(isset($this->data)){
            return $this->data['special_price']; // $60.00
            }
            return $result; // $70.00
}
.....
```

> result in frontpage : $60.00 ,  result in webapi : $70.00 ( original special price)

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the sample code  [magento2-samples](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-external-links/Model/Plugin/Product/Repository.php) it's necessary to use afterGetList method in plugin class.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="change_special_price" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Repository"/>
</type>
```

**Vendor\Module\Plugin\Repository.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class Repository
{
public function afterGetList(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchResults $searchResult) {
    foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $product) {
            $product->setData('special_price',60.0000); //custom special price
        }
        return $searchResult;
    }
}
```